# Buzzing, quality loss. Relay control system

Tags: noise

I have been working on a home project and got a bit disappointed now..
It seems that the sound control I have been working on looses quality or something else is affecting the sound quality with a very annoying buzz.

The buzz seems to be influenced by the colours on the screen on my main machine, ex: when gaming, if I turn and look up in the sky the screen gets brighter therefore the buzz intensifies, if I turn to a dark wall or so the buzz diminishes.

This is a home made control system, here are some of the details:

- The audio output of my main machine (Jack) goes into the first - Relay (the cable is stripped and the wires are connected directly into the relay's contacts); as I have knowledge and experience working in electricity I made sure each wire makes proper contact with each contact from the Relay
- From the Relay1 the Normally Closed contact (out) goes to Relay2 common contact (in)
- and from Relay2 the NC contact (out) goes to Relay3 common contact (in)
- The Relay3's NC contact (out) is the main and most used output, which is where the main Audio System is connected
- All Grounds are connected together
- Each cable is no longer than 2m
- The Audio output panel is actually the end of each Jack cable (female) (as in the image)
- Each Relay deals with only one cable (ex: R - right) then it goes to the next one
- Longest distance between cables is *2m + 2m + ~0.5m = max ~5m*

The buzz is notable in the Audio System as it is in the Headphones (in the Headphones seems to be a bit more intense).

On low volume the buzz is almost not present.

(I CAN'T POST MORE THAN 2 LINKS)

Please search on Amazon these product codes:

- cables: B007OH6QLY
- relay module: B0148BMACW

I do not have knowledge in audio performance or issues, just basics.

**Any help, ideas or links are much appreciated.**

Would this amplifier solve my problem? (I intend to use only: input (from main machine) -> amplify -> output to the Relay)

- amplifier: B000KIPT30

Devices:[image: devices]

Relay diagram: [image: this relay diagram]

Comment: by all means migrate to Elec Eng, but you do need to keep the audio ground separate from the processing (rPi) ground. Also look for bleed from the relay control board.

Comment: How do you know the noise is coming from your external system and not coming from your sound card?

Comment: While this may not solve your problem, it may help a little: I would re-wire the system so the audio only has to go through one relay contact, rather than a daisy-chain - input to the COM terminal of all relays in parallel, and ignore the NC contacts.  Also, the relays you have are decribed as "high current".  For low-level audio, you really need relays specified for switching very low currents.

Comment: - @Mark the ground is separated, it's only between the audio cables

Comment: @Samuel the machine is brand new, and decently powerful, I doubt that the sound card is a problem, this is the MB: https://www.scan.co.uk/3xs/products/info/2812178

Comment: @Peter Bennett I believe you might have a point there, passing through one relay seems fine, would you recommend any specific relay module? any links?

Comment: @4673_j If it's new you have no experience with it working correctly? Try testing it without the additional setup to see if your soundcard is the issue.

Comment: @Samuel Sound card output tested directly to headphones and speakers, it works fine and sound is clear

Comment: Reed relays should be appropriate for low level audio - look for relays with contacts rated for no more than 500 mA.

Comment: @PeterBennett I have seen the advantages of reed relays; are there any boards with these relays similar to the one I am using now? I do not have electronic knowledge to build the board myself..

Answer (score 1):

Suspect the RFI of Raspberry operation, at very high frequencies and very fast edges, coming thru the coil-drive to the relays, is coupling to the Audio.

You may be hearing the program-execution RFI.

Put 0.01uF (10nF, 10,000pF) to GND, on each drive-signal to the relay PCB.
Which GND. Right at the Raspberry PCB. Beware the surge currents as the MCU charges and discharges the capacitors. The MCU may be damaged.

Thus ferrite beads into 0.001uF, to the relay coil, would be safer.